# Bash Loop to rename files with spaces and dates in human format

Tags: bash

I have a lot of log files named like "Mon, May 22, 2017.log"  I am hoping to rename them to a typical date format (yyyy-mm-dd.log).  Right now I will be more than happy to settle for yyyy-mmm-dd.log.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `date` command to parse them and then print the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a couple of different ideas but ended up making a small script which actually works better for me because there were a number of other things I needed to do to sanitize my files besides just rename me.

The script is:

```
FILENAME=$(basename "$1")
FILENAME="${FILENAME%.*}"
NEWNAME=$(date -d "$FILENAME" +%Y%m%d)
mv "$1" "$NEWNAME".log
```

I then run the script using this command:

```
find . -iname "*.log" -exec ./test.sh {} \;
```

Probably not the most elegant or efficient answer out there but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
for i in *.log; do mv "$i" "$(awk -F '[\ ,.]' '{print $6 "-" $3 "-" $4}' <<< "$i")".log;done
```

But of course some deeper parsing of the used date format would be preferable.

Comment: Bunch of missing quotes here. Run this through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds.

Comment: (Also, this is really inefficient, running `awk` once per filename -- if I were writing this myself, I'd regex-match the names in native bash, and thus avoid all the overhead of spawning a subshell for the command substitution, creating a temporary file to hold the herestring, executing an external process with its stdin connected to that tempfile, etc).

Comment: The quotes are fine as the output won't generate any whitespaces. Of course you are right about the efficieny, but I don't worry as the logfiles won't be that many, at a rate of one per day.

Comment: You don't know that it won't generate whitespace -- your awk expression spits on spaces only; if input filenames had tabs, they could be present in the output.

Comment: Also, lack of quoting can cause problems without whitespace. If you have an input filename with literal asterisks in it, you *really* don't want those replaced with names of other files in the working directory.

Comment: Also, quote the expansion in `<<< "$i"`.

Comment: The presented format seemed to be well defined, but here you go. I changed it.

Comment: No matter how well the input is defined -- writing software that behaves in unexpected ways (as opposed to either correct handling or graceful error detection and exit) when expected preconditions aren't met is a great deal of why divergence between theory and practice is as unpleasant as it is. I once saw a case where multiple TB of records that were used for billing data were deleted because someone didn't quote their script (and a bug in a separate piece of software generated an "impossible" filename in that script's input directory).

Comment: I have to agree. Well said.

Answer (score 0):

In your selected folder, you can try something like this:

```
for file in *.log; do filename=${file%%.*};convertedDate=$(date -d"$filename" +%Y-%m-%d) && mv "$file" "$convertedDate.log"; done
```

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'` is not a replacement for correct quoting. Literal newlines are possible in filenames.

Comment: You can remove the `IFS` modificaiton and replace your `if` block with a *compound expression*, e.g. `convertedDate=$(date -d "$filename" +%Y-%m-%d) && mv "$file" "$convertedDate.log"`

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you both for the suggestions.